# Create a List of a Referenced Type

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am attempting to create a function to which I will pass the type of my Object and the function will use that Type to create a list of that Object.GetType

```
Public Function DoSomething(ByRef ObjectType As Type)
    Dim List As List(Of ObjectType)

    Return 0
End Function
```

The problem I am having is that the list creation proccess doesn't accept reference types in its construction.

I've tried passing on the Object itself as Object and then use the .GetType() function to create the list but it doesn't accept that also.

Any help would me appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is what Generics are for. You can code your function as `Function DoSomething(Of T)() As List(Of T)` `Return New List(Of T)` `End Function` and call it like this `Dim myIntList As List(Of Integer) = DoSomething(Of Integer)()`

Comment: @Blackwood - It's not clear if the OP has the type `T` at compile-time or it that only have `ObjectType As Type` at run-time.

Comment: @Enigmativity Good point, although I don't know why the OP would need an `ObjectType As T` at run-time.

Comment: @Blackwood - If you write loosely coupled code it comes up quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Function DoSomething(ByRef ObjectType As Type) As IList
    Return CType(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(ObjectType)), IList)
End Function
```